# Sentence correction

Tags: syntax

I've been told the following caption for a video about deglaciation looks awkward,

> "Highly impressive footage of the effects of climate change that is
>   not happening wink wink"

because of the

> "the effects of climate change that is not happening"

part.

There I want to ironically contrast (thus the *wink wink*) the fact everyone seem to avoid such an important topic as the climate change.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’ve edited your question in the hopes of making it specific enough to be re-opened.

Comment: For me, some of the awkwardness comes from expecting a number agreement here: “the **effects** of climate change that **is** not happening” (even though the lack of agreement is ultimately seen as correct). I think some punctuation would help the situation a lot, and StoneyB’s addition of a comma and the word “which” is a good start. This might be a good situation for em dashes to indicate self-interruption or an [aside](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/aside#ld_entry_v2_jumplink_aside_2). _“. . .which is, of course, not happening—wink wink!”_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything particularly awkward in your sentence; but the rhetorical effect might be a little stronger if you wrote:

> Highly impressive footage of the effects of climate change, which of course is not happening *wink wink*.